# regular expression to get 4th character from last

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to get a regular expression that can pick the last fourth character in the string.

For Ex. If "system" is a string I want to pick "s", I cannot check that from starting as the number of characters from start are not fixed.

So far I have only reached to : `/.{3}$/g` , but it is taking last three character ans not the character after that.

Can someone help me in the same?

Comment: I don't think JS has back tracing in regex. I'd suggest `str.charAt(str.length - 4)`

Comment: Or `s.substr(s.length-4, 1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any special reason for `substr`?

Comment: @Rajesh: "I don't think JS has back tracing in regex": what a strange idea.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte maybe he was thinking about lookbehinds? Which is still off since it's a lookahead which could be useful here, which JS support.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You can write `s.substr(-4, 1)` (when the start index is negative `s.length` is implicit)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I was not sure hence *I don't think*. Apologies if its not accurate. And yes I was referring to *lookbehind*. Apologies for confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.(?=.{3}$)` works with the whole expression matching, not just a capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

You’d have to use a group:

```
/(.).{3}$/
```

The full match here will be `stem`, and group 1 would be `s` (you can see for yourself here: https://regex101.com/r/dZwhcu/1)

You could solve it as follows:

```
var matches = 'system'.match(/(.).{3}$/); //=> ['stem', 's']
if (matches[1] === 's') {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const reg = /.*(.).{3}$/g
const str = 'this is astring'

console.log(
  str.replace(reg, '$1')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using substring like that :

```
function lastFourLetters(str)
{
   if (str.length < 5)
       return str;
   return str.substring(str.length - 4 , 4); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `/([a-z]).{3}$/g` then in your result, you can use the value from first capture group. Change the class just in case you want a wider or different selection